# unable to filter object with name `end` using JQ

Tags: jq

I am trying to parse a json file using jq.

```
$cat ipres.txt
{
    "start":    {
        "connected":    [{
                "socket":   5,
                "local_host":   "10.8.0.3",
                "local_port":   36068,
                "remote_host":  "10.8.0.2",
                "remote_port":  5201
            }],
        "version":  "iperf 3.1.2",
        "system_info":  "Linux sid-Vostro-3700 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64",
        "timestamp":    {
            "time": "Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:08:10 GMT",
            "timesecs": 1461330490
        },
        "connecting_to":    {
            "host": "10.8.0.2",
            "port": 5201
        },
        "cookie":   "sid-Vostro-3700.1461330486.892347.18",
        "test_start":   {
            "protocol": "UDP",
            "num_streams":  1,
            "blksize":  8192,
            "omit": 0,
            "duration": 2,
            "bytes":    0,
            "blocks":   0,
            "reverse":  0
        }
    },
    "intervals":    [{
            "streams":  [{
                    "socket":   5,
                    "start":    0,
                    "end":  2.0002,
                    "seconds":  2.0002,
                    "bytes":    253952,
                    "bits_per_second":  1.01571e+06,
                    "packets":  31,
                    "omitted":  false
                }],
            "sum":  {
                "start":    0,
                "end":  2.0002,
                "seconds":  2.0002,
                "bytes":    253952,
                "bits_per_second":  1.01571e+06,
                "packets":  31,
                "omitted":  false
            }
        }],
    "end":  {
        "streams":  [{
                "udp":  {
                    "socket":   5,
                    "start":    0,
                    "end":  2.0002,
                    "seconds":  2.0002,
                    "bytes":    253952,
                    "bits_per_second":  1.01571e+06,
                    "jitter_ms":    828.078,
                    "lost_packets": 0,
                    "packets":  24,
                    "lost_percent": 0,
                    "out_of_order": 0
                }
            }],
        "sum":  {
            "start":    0,
            "end":  2.0002,
            "seconds":  2.0002,
            "bytes":    253952,
            "bits_per_second":  1.01571e+06,
            "jitter_ms":    828.078,
            "lost_packets": 0,
            "packets":  24,
            "lost_percent": 0
        },
        "cpu_utilization_percent":  {
            "host_total":   7.7914,
            "host_user":    1.09745,
            "host_system":  6.69392,
            "remote_total": 0,
            "remote_user":  0,
            "remote_system":    0
        }
    },
    "test": 0
}
```

But when i try to filter the end object, my command fails.

```
$cat ipres.txt | jq .end
error: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting $end
.end
 ^^^
1 compile error
```

If i change the `end` object to some other name for example `end1`, i can able to filter. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you are after:

```
jq '.end' ipres.txt
```

If you are still getting the same erroneous output - then you may be using an older / badly built version of jq.

Comment: exactly. But what you have given is a simple version of  `$cat ipres.txt | jq .end`. Nevertheless the output for both is same(error mentioned in my question).

Comment: Then consider re-evaluating / looking at your source file:`ipres.txt` - OR the version of `jq` that you are using. Did you build `jq` yourself? - I copy pasted your files which works fine.

Comment: yes my fault. I was using an older version of jq. Tried with JQ 1.5 and it is working. Could you update your answer indicating your previous comment (version mismatch) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are evidently using an early version of jq -- perhaps jq 1.3, which is well out-of-date and which has some limitations with respect to the abbreviated syntax: `.foo`.

That is, you would have to write `.["end"]` in jq 1.3, since "end" is a keyword (as in: `if ... then ... else ... end`).

In jq 1.4 and jq 1.5, one can write `.end`